# Using Supervisord, how can I start a brand new worker via supervisorctl without restarting other workers?

Tags: supervisord

Let's say I have a number of existing workers running in supervisord. I want to add a new worker to the group as well as start the new worker. I perform the following steps:

1. I modify the file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` and add the new worker config
2. Back on the command line, I enter `sudo supervisorctl`
3. I run `reread` to read the new configuration file settings.
4. Attempting to run `start workers:exampleWorkerName` gives the error *workers:"exampleWorkerName": ERROR (no such process)*

So, my question is, **how can I start this new worker process without affecting my other existing workers?** I'd rather not perform a `supervisorctl reload` or `/etc/init.d/supervisord restart` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to run `supervisorctl update`.

Comment: Running `supervisorctl update` will unfortunately restart all workers. Here's a sample of the output: `workers: stopped` followed by `workers: updated process group`. The worker status shows they were all restarted.

Comment: I should probably also say that I am using groups allowing me to restart all workers at once, so this might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This command only updates the changes

```
supervisorctl reread
```

Restarts the applications whose configuration has changed.

```
supervisorctl update.
```

and

```
supervisorctl restart all
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are still interested, after running

```
supervisorctl reread
```

you can try running

```
supervisorctl add <newWorker>
```